# Is lock or volatile required when worker threads write non-competitively to local or class variables?

Tags: c#, variables, locking, task, volatile

For the case below, when there is no competition for writes between the worker threads, are locks or volatile still required?   Any difference in the answer if "Peek" access is not required at "G".

```
class A 
{
   Object _o; // need volatile (position A)?
   Int _i;    // need volatile (position B)?

   Method()
   {
      Object o;
      Int i;

      Task [] task = new Task[2]
      {
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
              _o = f1();   // use lock() (position C)?
              o  = f2();   // use lock() (position D)?
         } 
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
              _i = g1();   // use lock() (position E)?
              i  = g2();   // use lock() (position F)?
         }          
      }

      // "Peek" at _o, _i, o, i (position G)?

      Task.WaitAll(tasks);

      // Use _o, _i, o, i (position H)?
}
```

Comment: Servy's answer is correct, but be careful about your expectations at position G, since you might get some non-intuitive results. For example, you might `o` assigned to the new object, but `_o` still being null, despite that they should have happened in reverse order.

Comment: Additionally, if the intention behind your "peek" is to process the results of a completed task before all the others have also completed, then the correct way to go would be to replace your `WaitAll` with a loop of `WaitAny` calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writes to reference types (i.e. `Object`) and word-sized value types (i.e. `int` in a 32 bit system) are atomic.  This means that when you peek at the values (position 6) you can be sure that you either get the old value or the new value, but not something else (if you had a type such as a large struct it could be spliced, and you could read the value when it was half way through being written).  You don't *need* a `lock` or `volatile`, so long as you're willing to accept the potential risk of reading stale values.

Note that because there is no memory barrier introduced at this point (a `lock` or use of `volatile` both add one) it's possible that the variable has been updated in the other thread, but the current thread isn't observing that change; it can be reading a "stale" value for (potentially) quite some time after it has been changed in the other thread.  The use of `volatile` will ensure that the current thread can observe changes to the variable sooner.

You can be sure that you'll have the appropriate value after the call to `WaitAll`, even without a `lock` or `volatile`.

Also note that while you can be sure the reference to the reference type is written atomically, your program makes no guarantee about the observed order of any changes to the actual object that the reference refers to.  Even if, from the point of view of the background thread, the object is initialized before it is assigned to the instance field, it may not happen in that order.  The other thread can therefore observe the write of the reference tot he object but then follow that reference and find an object in an initialize, or partially initialized, state.  Introducing a memory barrier (i.e. through the use of a `volatile` variable can potentially allow you to prevent the runtime from making such re-orderings, thus ensuring that doesn't happen.  This is why it's [better to just not do this in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17795584/1159478) and to just have the two tasks return the results that they generate rather than manipulating a closed over variable.

`WaitAll` will introduce a memory barrier, in addition to ensuring that the two tasks are actually finished, which means that you know that the variables are up-to-date and will not have the old stale values.

Comment: @EricLippert: I disagree. The atomicity of the writes is what would make all the difference if considering `int` vs `long` assignments on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: @EricLippert At position G (6 in previous revision) there is no memory barrier, in addition to the task not being done.  It's still possible for either of the two values to be selected, even without a memory barrier.  After `WaitAll` you can be sure all reads will result in the correct values *because* it introduces a memory barrier.  Given that, you could assert that the answer is insufficiently explained (since I don't explain why my last sentence is true), but I fail to see what about it is *incorrect*?

Comment: @Douglas: That you disagree does not change the facts.  What matters here is that the processor and jitter not be allowed to make optimizations that would cause stale values to be read out of the variables. An atomic read of the wrong value is still a read of the wrong value.

Comment: @Servy: OK, you make a good point; I suppose this is correct but just not sufficiently motivated. The atomicity seems like a distraction from the real problem, which is whether a barrier is introduced.

Comment: @EricLippert The answer states that it's possible to read either the initial value or the changed value.  The fact that there's no memory barrier means that you can indeed be reading a stale value; that value will be the initial value.  That the write is atomic means that you know the variable will have one of two values; the old or the new, it won't have a third value in which a portion of the bits were written, but not all of them.

Comment: @EricLippert: Since there is no explicit synchronization, "stale" does not have any meaning. A read of the old value is still correct.

Comment: @Servy: You need to be careful about reference types (i.e. `o` and `_o`). Although the pointer will be written atomically, you're not guaranteed that all the fields of the new instance would have been propagated. Thus, you may still get inconsistent reads if you're accessing the object's fields.

Comment: @Douglas: To be fair Servy did mention half-baked state problem with complex data structures. Also, it's a stretch, but one might argue that `Task.WaitAll` is the explicit synchronization; not unlike using `WaitHandle.WaitOne` and the like. I'm not disgreeing with you per se; just playing the devil's advocate role at the moment :)

Comment: @Servy: OK, I see your point now, and I withdraw my objection. When you say "you don't need a lock or volatile" you mean "if you're willing to live with reading any combination of old or new values, you don't need a lock or volatile". However I note that the user did not specify what code would go there, and therefore we're reasoning from a position of ignorance. I find it difficult enough to predict what code I can see does; code that is invisible is a lot harder to analyze!

Comment: @BrianGideon: Yes, I was considering the `WaitAll` as the synchronization point. Reading the unassigned values of the variables *after* the `WaitAll` call would be considered stale (and undesirable). However, reading the unassigned values *before* it would not, since there's no logical constraint on the order in which the assignments and the reads take place.

Comment: @EricLippert Hopefully some of the added edits/comments about all the things to worry about will help to drive the point home about why this method should be avoided more effectively.

Comment: Couldn't he use `Interlocked.Exchange` in positions C, D, E, and F? With temporaries, of course. That wouldn't help at position G, although I suppose you could play funny with `CompareExchange`.

Comment: @JimMischel Since the reader still has no way of knowing if the task is even done it seems out of place.  It means that the calling thread will pick up the changes a bit sooner, and it can ensure the referenced object is initialized before it's read from the other thread, but in general it just doesn't make a whole lot of sense to be doing it in the first place.

Comment: On the "following that reference...to find an object in an initialize, or partially initialized, state."  Isn't there just a single "heap" object?  And so if f1() in worker thread has updated/created the object, returned the value (and exited its stack frame!), why wouldn't that heap object perfectly reflect those changes?

Comment: @crokusek The runtime will ensure that all of those actions are observed in a particular behavior when in a single threaded environment.  It's allowed to reorder things to its heart content so long as that single thread can't observe the difference.  This means that it could end up returning the reference to the object before it has finished manipulating it, even though the order of the code returns it after it initializes it.  That's what makes multithreaded code so hard to work with; you can't make almost any assumptions about order until you enforce them with synchronization constructs.

Answer (score 7):

The safe thing to do is to not do this in the first place. Don't write a value on one thread and read the value on another thread in the first place. Make a `Task<object>` and a `Task<int>` that return the values to the thread that needs them, rather than making tasks that modify variables across threads.

If you are hell bent on writing to variables across threads then you need to guarantee two things. First, that the jitter does not choose optimizations that would cause reads and writes to be moved around in time, and second, that a memory barrier is introduced. The memory barrier limits the *processor* from moving reads and writes around in time in certain ways.

As Brian Gideon notes in his answer, you get a memory barrier from the `WaitAll`, but I do not recall offhand if that is a documented guarantee or just an implementation detail.

As I said, I would not do this in the first place. If I were forced to, I would at least make the variables I was writing to marked as volatile.

Comment: I don't think its documented either (at least not definitely). It's just my *assumption* albeit with near 100% certainty that it actually does generate a memory barrier. The point you make is still the same...just don't it this way to begin with!

Comment: [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Full_fences) states that it's always generated when waiting on a `Task` (just like when entering/leaving a `lock`). I don't know how authoritative that book is, although I've found it to be one of the best references on the subject.

Comment: @Douglas: I was the technical reviewer of the most recent edition of C# in a Nutshell, and that was a *hard job*, let me tell you. The Albaharis know their stuff.

Comment: I definitely agree. What I meant to say is that I don't know whether the behaviour explained in their book is implied to be part of the specification (and must be upheld by other frameworks, such as Mono), or whether it's a documentation of the .NET implementation.

Comment: Having read the Full_fences section douglas linked to, I have concluded that Eric is right; avoiding shared variables entirely is much safer.  The volatile keyword is more complex than it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

At position G you may observe the values `_o` and `_i` may retain their initialized values null and 0 respectively or they may contain the values written by the tasks. It is unpredictable at this position.

However, at position H you force the issue in two different ways. First, you have guaranteed that both tasks finished and thus the writes are completed. Second, `Task.WaitAll` will generate a memory barrier which will guarantee that the main thread will observe the new values published by the tasks.

So, in this particular example an explicit lock or memory barrier generator (`volatile`) is not technically required.